# Fill out a 3x3 square with 9 different positive integers such that the product of each row, column, and diagonal is equal to each other

Tags: magic-square

I have an idea, which is to put 2 in the middle and have the rest multiply up to an even number, but I can't seem to find an even number with that many factors.

Comment: Just for clarification, by 9 different positive integers you don't just mean $1,2,\dots,9$?

Comment: You can use any positive integers.

Comment: Nevermind, it's unsolvable if only 1 to 9 are allowed

Comment: If you write each of the 9 entries as a power of 2 with an unknown exponent, then it will work provided the 3x3 square with just the exponents is a magic square with all distinct entries.

Comment: please check: (http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3607/can-you-fill-a-3x3-grid-with-these-numbers-so-the-products-of-the-rows-and-colum)

Answer (score 4):

Hint : Take a magic $3\times 3$-square and replace every entry $x$ by $2^x$